# Move only single nav items to the right in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, bootstrap-5

I have a navbar programmed with bootstrap 5 and as you can see in the picture I just want to move the last three nav-items to the right.[image: Move direction of the items]

I have already tried `ms-auto`, which resulted in all my nav-items being moved to the right, but I only want to move three to the right.

Comment: share your code instead of image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 2 ul classes:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Navigation-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand abs" href="#">Navbar 1</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapseNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#myAlert" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="" data-bs-target="#myModal" data-bs-toggle="modal">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks - works with navbar-toggler

Answer (score 0):

To move the last three navigation items to the right, you can split the navigation items into two separate `ul` elements. The `ul` containing the right-aligned items should have the class `ms-auto`.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <!-- left aligned items -->
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <!-- right aligned items -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```